# How to extract ext4 filesystem on FAT16 partition

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, beagleboard

I have root file system for beagle bone black board and want to extract it one of the partitions of SD card which is of FAT16 type.

Is it possible?

Kindly share your views.

Comment: You can extract (copy) files from one file system to another. But when there are different file systems (ext4 and FAT16), some things may not work, for example FAT16 cannot store files bigger than a certain size, permissions and ownership cannot be transferred (because of limitations, when FAT16 is used by linux) and linux links are different from shortcuts in FAT. -- This is maybe not what you are asking for. Maybe you ask if it is possible to change the file system in a partition from FAT16 to ext4. Yes, this is possible. (But it means that all previous data in the partition will be lost.)

Comment: Thank you for reply..I got your point..can I copy ext4 type file system to FAT16 partition?

Comment: The partition is only a container, and it can be filled with a file system. You can create a file system alias 'format' the partition with several different file systems. The new file system will overwrite the old one, so if you create an ext4 file system, the previous FAT16 file system will disappear. **`gparted`** is a tool, that you can use for this task.